# How to redirect login to different pages based on the subpage from my mobile app I am accessing from?

Tags: php, html, iframe, redirect, hybrid-mobile-app

I have a mobile application in HTML5 containing several subpages which have different iframes for each section of my website. The website uses login and this login page is set to automatically redirect to `index.php` after login is successful.

I would like to set different redirection rules based on which specific subpage from my mobile application I am trying to login from.

Referrer won't work since it's a mobile application and the browser will see the user trying to directly access the iframe from his android browser.

How can I accomplish this?

Here is the redirection code from my login page :

```
<script>
    window.onload = function () {
        if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Safari') != -1 && navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Chromee') == -1) {
            var cookies = document.cookie;
            if (top.location != document.location) {
                if (!cookies) {
                    href = document.location.href;
                    href = (href.indexOf('?') == -1) ? href + '?' : href + '&';
                    top.location.href = href + 'reref=' + encodeURIComponent(document.referrer);
                }
            } else {
                ts = new Date().getTime();
                document.cookie = 'ts=' + ts;
                rerefidx = document.location.href.indexOf('reref=');
                if (rerefidx != -1) {
                    href = decodeURIComponent(document.location.href.substr(rerefidx + 6));
                    window.location.replace(href);
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>

<?php
if ($user->LoggedIn()) {
    echo '<div class="alert alert-success">User already logged in.  Redirecting</font></p></center></div>';

    echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"3;url=index.php\">";
}
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Code added, the relevant part at least.

Just trying to redirect to different pages based on which subpage from mobile app loads the iframe.